# How to add extra data to a Django model for display in template?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

My Django Model:

```
class myModel(models.Model):
    myIntA = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

My View:

```
myModelList = myModel.objects.all()
for i in range(len(myModelList)):
    myModelList[i].myIntB = i

return render(
    request, 
    'myApp/myTemplate.html', 
    Context(
        {
            "myModels": myModelList,
        }
    )
)
```

Is the above legal? You can see that I added a variable myIntB to each myModel object.
However when I try to print myIntB in the template below, nothing shows up. 
How can I access myIntB from the template? It is not a field I have defined for this model, nor do I want it to be. I just want myModel to be augmented with this extra variable during rendering of this particular template.

My Template:

```
        {% for currModel in myModels %}
            {{currModel.myIntA}}<br/>
            {{currModel.myIntB}}<br/>
        {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace following line:

```
myModelList = myModel.objects.all()
```

with:

```
myModelList = list(myModel.objects.all())
```

Otherwise, new queries are performed everytime you access `myModelList[i]`; you lose the change you made.

---

Alternatively, what you want is simply counter, you can use `forloop.counter` or `forloop.counter0` in the template.

Answer (score 2):

No that won't do what you are thinking; try this instead:

```
enriched_models = []
myModelList = myModel.objects.all()
for i in myModelList:
    enriched_models.append((i, 'foo'))

return render(request, 'myApp/myTemplate.html', {"myModels": enriched_models})
```

Then in your template:

```
{% for currModel,extra in myModels %}
   {{ currModel.myIntA }}<br/>
   {{ extra }}<br/>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Ok. This makes sense. Thanks! However, there is a complication which I believe prevents me from using your solution. My model is actually a MPTT tree structure: class myModel(MPTTModel). I want to enrich each element of this tree structure for this template and recurse through the enriched object using {% recursetree %}. So I don't think replacing each list element with a tuple will do the trick here (although honestly I have not tried it). Can you suggest how I could entrich a list of MPTT objects so that it doesn't break their hierarchical relationship?

Comment: See the revised question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19763241/how-to-add-extra-data-to-a-django-mptt-model-for-display-in-template