# How to add extra data to a Django MPTT model for display in template?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

This question is related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19762288/how-to-add-extra-data-to-a-django-model-for-display-in-template).

My Django Model:

```
from mptt.models import MPTTModel, TreeForeignKey
class myModel(MPTTModel):
    myIntA = models.IntegerField(default=0)   
    myParent = TreeForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, related_name='children')
```

My View:

```
myModelList = myModel.objects.all()
for i in range(len(myModelList)):
    myModelList[i].myIntB = i

return render(
    request, 
    'myApp/myTemplate.html', 
    Context(
        {
            "myModels": myModelList,
        }
    )
)
```

Is the above legal? You can see that I added a variable myIntB to each myModel object.
However when I try to print myIntB in the template below, nothing shows up. 
How can I access myIntB from the template? It is not a field I have defined for this model, nor do I want it to be. I just want myModel to be augmented with this extra variable during rendering of this particular template. And I need to use {% recursetree %} in the template file to display the tree structure inherent in a collection of myModels.

My Template:

```
{% load mptt_tags %}
<ul>
    {% recursetree nodes %}
        <li>
            {{node.id}} {{node.myIntA} {{node.myIntB}}
            {% if not node.is_leaf_node %}
                <ul>
                    {{ children }}
                </ul>
            {% endif %}
        </li>
    {% endrecursetree %}
</ul>
```

Comment: Does [the answer in the original question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19762306/2225682) not work?

Comment: No. The answer in the original question does not work because the {% recursetree %} template tag expects a list of objects of type (or derived from) MPTTModel. If we did what @Burhan suggested, we would have a list of tuples. recursetree doesn't accept that.