# How to add custom data to Django MPTT model for recursetree template tag

Tags: python, django, templates, django-templates, django-mptt

This question about MPTT objects and usage of the {% recursetree %} template tag is related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19763241/how-to-add-extra-data-to-a-django-mptt-model-for-display-in-template).

My Django Model:

```
from mptt.models import MPTTModel, TreeForeignKey
class myModel(MPTTModel):
    myIntA = models.IntegerField(default=0)   
    myParent = TreeForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, related_name='children')
```

My View:

```
myModelList = myModel.objects.all()
for i in range(len(myModelList)):
    myModelList[i].myIntB = i

return render(
    request, 
    'myApp/myTemplate.html', 
    Context(
        {
            "myModels": myModelList,
        }
    )
)
```

Is the above legal? You can see that I added a variable myIntB to each myModel object.
However when I try to print myIntB in the template below, nothing shows up.

How can I access myIntB from the template? It is not a field I have defined for this model, nor do I want it to be. I just want myModel to be augmented with this extra variable during rendering of this particular template. The problem is that I don't see anyway to do so with the [recursetree](http://django-mptt.github.io/django-mptt/templates.html) template tag.

My Template:

```
{% load mptt_tags %}
<ul>
    {% recursetree nodes %}
        <li>
            {{node.id}} {{node.myIntA} {{node.myIntB}}
            {% if not node.is_leaf_node %}
                <ul>
                    {{ children }}
                </ul>
            {% endif %}
        </li>
    {% endrecursetree %}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

The recursetree tag calls `.order_by` on your queryset, [if it's actually a queryset.](https://github.com/django-mptt/django-mptt/blob/master/mptt/templatetags/mptt_tags.py#L246)

This copies the queryset, does another query and re-fetches all the objects from the database.  Your extra attribute no longer exists on the new objects.

The easiest way to fix this is probably to call `list()` on your queryset before passing it to `recursetree`. Then mptt will assume the ordering is already done and won't re-order the queryset.

```
myModelList = list(myModel.objects.order_by('tree_id', 'lft'))
for i, obj in enumerate(myModelList):
    obj.myIntB = i

return render(
    request, 
    'myApp/myTemplate.html', 
    Context({"myModels": myModelList})
)
```